# Pandas shift function: apply shift of a df with the shift period being a list of value from another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to shift the rows of a df column with the shifting period based on another df colums with all the shifting variables:

```
      value | shiftperiod | shiftedvalue
row1    a         0             a
row2    b         0             b
row3    c         1             b
row4    d         3             a
row5    e         4             a
row6    f         2             d
row7    g         1             f
```

Initially I thought this could be done as:

```
df['shiftedvalue']=df['value'].shift(df['shiftperiod'])
```

However, obviously the shift function does not take 'df' as the input type for period.

In this case, how should I efficiently write a code to achieve this dynamic shifting based on another df column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) indexing for that:

```
# convert the "value" to numpy array
a = df['value'].to_numpy()

# generate a 0->n range and subtract the shiftperiod 
idx = np.arange(len(df))-df['shiftperiod'].to_numpy()

# reindex, ensuring only valid indexes are used
df['shiftedvalue'] = np.where((idx>=0) & (idx<len(df)),
                              a[np.clip(idx, 0, len(df)-1)],
                              np.nan)
```

If you are sure that the `shiftperiod` can never yield a non existing position, you can simplify the last line to:

```
df['shiftedvalue'] = a[idx]
```

Or using a Series with a range index and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with conversion [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html):

```
s = df['value'].reset_index(drop=True)

df['shiftedvalue'] = s.reindex(s.index-df['shiftperiod']).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
     value  shiftperiod shiftedvalue
row1     a            0            a
row2     b            0            b
row3     c            1            b
row4     d            3            a
row5     e            4            a
row6     f            2            d
row7     g            1            f
```

Example with invalid `shiftperiod` values:

```
     value  shiftperiod shiftedvalue
row1     a            0            a
row2     b            0            b
row3     c            1            b
row4     d            3            a
row5     e            5          NaN
row6     f            2            d
row7     g           -1          NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if we can achieve the same result via using apply with a lambda function?

Comment: @manwong0606 maybe but why? this would be much less efficient

Comment: you are right. your suggested one: ```s = df['value'].reset_index(drop=True)

df['shiftedvalue'] = s.reindex(s.index-df['shiftperiod']).to_numpy()```

does not involve a loop calculation like .apply(lambda) would else do otherwise. Am I correct?

Comment: please ask a new question with a reproducible input/output and a clear description of what you want.

Comment: The more advanced question now becomes: If I want to create the column to return the values with dynamic shift (based on the shift period column) but also based on a particular column as per 'return colum' column). What would you suggest?

Reference question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77831655/pandas-dataframe-dynamic-shift-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: Can I ask why we need to use to_numpy in your previous suggested response above?

Comment: Sure, because we dropped the Series index to have a range (0,1,2...) it would be incompatible with the original index (row1,row2...). If you try without `to_numpy()` you'll have all NaNs due to reindexing.