# Pandas Dataframe dynamic shift horizontally and vertically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to shift the rows and columns of a df column with the shifting period based on another df columns and another df column that specifies the column to return:

```
      a  b  c return_column  shift_period
row1  1  3  3             a             1
row2  3  4  5             c             1
row3  4  2  9             c             2
row4  5  3  0             b             3
row5  6  5  2             a             4
row6  7  6  3             b             5
```

My expectation would be:

```
       a  b  c return_column  shift_period  answer
row1  1  3  3             a             1      NaN
row2  3  4  5             c             1       3
row3  4  2  9             c             2       3
row4  5  3  0             b             3       3
row5  6  5  2             a             4       1
row6  7  6  3             b             5       3
```

Previously, someone suggests the following (for applying dynamic shift only as follows):

```
s = df['value'].reset_index(drop=True)
df['shiftedvalue'] = s.reindex(s.index-df['shiftperiod']).to_numpy()
```

However, if I also want to consider the return column, any other way? I thought of using a combination of .apply and lambda function (despite slower processing time), but even so I couldnt think of the solution with apply

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the [previous approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77756468/16343464) with [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels):

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['return_column'])

df['answer'] = (df.reset_index()
                  .reindex(index=(s.index-df['shift_period']).to_numpy(),
                           columns=cols)
                  .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
               )
```

Or, with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

```
# identify the column to use
c_idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['return_column'])

# convert the "value" to numpy array
a = df[cols].to_numpy()

# generate a 0->n range and subtract the shiftperiod 
idx = np.arange(len(df))-df['shift_period'].to_numpy()

# reindex, ensuring only valid indexes are used
df['answer'] = np.where((idx>=0) & (idx<len(df)),
                        a[np.clip(idx, 0, len(df)-1), c_idx],
                        np.nan)
```

Output:

```
      a  b  c return_column  shift_period  answer
row1  1  3  3             a             1     NaN
row2  3  4  5             c             1     3.0
row3  4  2  9             c             2     3.0
row4  5  3  0             b             3     3.0
row5  6  5  2             a             4     1.0
row6  7  6  3             b             5     3.0
```